# get JSON file on input change only once

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a JSON file on my backend with suggested words for autocomplete in the search.

I don`t want the JSON to load every time the page loads (for performance), I want only when someone wants to use the search.

For autocomplete, I am using bootstrat3-typeahead (https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

this is the script that loads the json:

```
    var searchSuggest = "http://localhost/searchSuggest.json";
    $.get(searchSuggest, function(data){
        $("#input-search").typeahead({
             source:data, 
             autoSelect: false, 
             afterSelect: function(){
                 // local function the commits the search
                 search($("#input-search"))
             } 
    });
```

I was thinking about loads the JSON on input change event, but how can I get it only once?

Comment: use some flag and then load JSON if it not loaded already

Comment: have you checked the network tab in the browser to see how many times it _actually_ loads it, or whether it loads it from the cache on subsequent requests?

Comment: yes @ADyson the request is made each time i press a key (input change)

Comment: and is it cached, or not?

Comment: no...i don't want to be cached, because the list is changing often. It seems to work with @Damien Gilles answer using one on 'input change' event :)

Comment: " the list is changing often"...it's a static JSON file you're serving. Is some background process updating the file on the server in the meantime?

Comment: Having said all that, looking at it again...since you are requesting the data and _then_ building the typeahead, I cannot see how it really be inefficient. What you pass to the typeahead is actually effectively static data - you just give it an object. Typeahead doesn't know you got it from an AJAX request. Watch the network tab in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6p31hu08/ - it only requests the URL once at the beginning. You can type in the textbox as much as you like and it never makes any more AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.one to have an event handler on input change executed only once: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: how do you suggest to integrate that with the typeahead plugin? And won't it just mean that the autocomplete only ever works once (as opposed to only downloading the JSON once, and then using it for multiple executions of the autocomplete)?

Comment: You can simply wrap all the code of calin24 in $.one. So $.get is executed only once when the user starts typing. typeahead needs to be set up only once to works all the time.